# Getting values from a many-many relationship using unassociated data (LINQ)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have the below (simplified) database set up in MVC 4/EF 6. Each class references the other using the standard `public virtual ICollection<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }` (and vice versa) in its model. I'm brand new to EF and C# and whatnot (but not SQL), so this is probably very simple, but I'm unsure of how to do this: I need to write a function that returns a list of every `SalesOrder.ExternalId` associated with a given `OrderChangeNotice.Id`. This has no sort of filtering on it so I know it's wrong, but here's an idea of the queries I've been trying:

```
ocnRepository.SelectMany(n => n.SalesOrders.Select(o => o.ExternalId)).ToList();
```

How would I correctly write this query?

Simplified DB schema:

[image: DB schema]

If it helps, here is the table mapping code (in the map file for `OrderChangeNotice`, no similar code exists in the map for `SalesOrder` as it is only required in one).

```
this.HasMany(o => o.SalesOrders)
    .WithMany(o => o.OrderChangeNotices)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("OCN_SalesOrders");
        m.MapLeftKey("OrderChangeNoticeId");
        m.MapRightKey("SalesOrderId");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm more used to NHibernate, but I think it should be something like this:

```
ocnRepository.SelectMany(n => n.SalesOrders)
             .Where(so => so.OrderChangeNoticeId == myOrderChangeNoticeId)
             .Select(o => o.ExternalId)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return a list of _all_ `ExternalId`s though? I don't see any sort of filtering in there. (Wish I were good enough with LINQPad to test this stuff.)

Comment: Forgot to add the `Where` clause. Updated the answer!

Comment: Just tried it. `so` is a `SalesOrder` object, so I can't do the comparison against anything there (it has no `OrderChangeNoticeId` property). I only put the join table in the image to clarify that it's a many-many relationship; EF handles that for me and it's never actually possible to directly query the join table itself. (This is why the `ICollection` navigation property is necessary in each of the classes.)

Comment: It's solely a declaration of all of the necessary variables, that's it. (Well, it has `using` statements as well, but I think you get my meaning.) The relevant line is `public virtual ICollection<OrderChangeNotice> OrderChangeNotices { get; set; }`. I have added the DB mapping code to the OP if it helps.

Comment: See if this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803840/querying-many-to-many-and-conditional-where